# Rewrite Links Array to include Nesting

Tags: 8, theming

I'm attempting to modify the language switcher links in a block so that the items are properly nested per my site's menu structure.

Currently, it outputs:

```
<ul>
<li>English Link</li>
<li>Japanese Link</li>
<li>Spanish Link</li>
</ul>
```

I need:

```
<ul>
<li>English Link</li>
<ul>
    <li>Japanese Link</li>
    <li>Spanish Link</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

The `$build['content']['#links']` array contains:

```
array (size=4)
  'en' => 
    array (size=5)
      'url' => 
        object(Drupal\Core\Url)[14062]
        ...
    'ja' => 
        array (size=5)
          'url' => 
            object(Drupal\Core\Url)[14062]
```

How can I modify this array so that elements are nested in a `ul` under the first link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the structure you're looking for is created by the template layer. I would not recommend changing the link array directly. A good example template is core's stable theme's [menu.html.twig](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/themes/stable/templates/navigation/menu.html.twig). It uses a recursive twig macro to create nested lists.